White screen on initial load in React
I’m having a problem with multiple production apps built with React. This issue has always been present, but now I want to address it. The problem is that my apps display a white screen when I paste the URL in the browser for the first time (after the initial render, navigation works well) or when I refresh the app. I have some information from Lighthouse, although I’m not sure if it’s useful.

In one app, I'm using react-router-dom v6 loaders to fetch all the data before rendering the components. In another app, I fetch the data in App.js. Despite these differences, both apps exhibit the same issue. Additionally, both apps use webpack.

This is because your browser loads empty HTML file, then loads scripts, then reads those scripts, parses, converts them into bytecode an only then starts executing them. During execution, you get your page populated. There is no other way to have content initially, other than render honest HTML page on the server and send that page to the browser.
You might want to either look into SSR for react and do it manually, or some frameworks, like Next.js, Vike, Remix, and others.

Why don't all pages have this issue? For example, Facebook, Instagram and many more use React, and they don't show a white screen. They are all using this SSR technique?

You can check it yourself if you look at the HTML they send from server (for example in network or sources panel in devtools)

Is it a bad idea to add a loader outside the #root and then in the index.js once the app is loaded, remove it from the dom? That way I can show the logo of the app or something on the white screen

That depends on your goal. Ideally you render your content on the server and then hydrate it on the client side if needed. If your data is static, you can prerender everything on a build step and don't bother with server runtime. Loader is beneficial for SPA, especially if it is accessible, but SSR still way better. It's important to note that first SPAs were usually for stuff that doesn't need any SEO and companies like Meta don't really afraid of loosing few users based on bad UI and UX.
